# How to format partition of the disk which has System & reserved files?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, formatting, disk-space, format

I wanted to format partition on my SSD, but it has System and reserved files. Does anybody know if I can just delete these files or move them to another disk?

[image]

[image]

Comment: WIthin Disk Mangement it should be as simple as formatting the entire disk. You can't of course delete the system partition, which Windows is using, from within Windows.  If you want to do that you need boot into WinPE and delete the partition. It's not clear, the reason, you are trying to delete your system disk from witin Windows.  Please clarify what you are trying to achieve exactly and the reason you need to delete the partition in the first place.

Comment: I want to delete this partion to use his space for Linux partion. This partion is not considered as system partion.

Comment: If you delete that particular drive, based on your system current system configuration, Windows would no longer boot.  In order to delete the partition, you would have to do so, outside of Windows as Disk Mangement would not allow you to delete a system partition. You might be under the mistakenly it's not a system disk but Windows is using that disk as a sytem disk.

Comment: Well, that partion is located on the same disk, where I installed Windows. Is it possible to reduce that partion?

Comment: You can shrink the partition with Disk Manager.

Comment: Could you add the screenshot of the entire Disk Management Screen to your post? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc I have added the screenshot

Comment: By the way, @Ramhound. I tried to shrink the volume, but it said that volumes that are used by system cannot be shrinked

Comment: Windows is using it to store a page file.  You should only store page files on your system disk.  If the disk is not intended to be a system disk, disable the page file, and your ability to delete the partition should be restored. It is strange you received that notification message, system disks, most certainly can be shrinked.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I have changed the page file settings

Comment: @Sandrai, it would be better if you answered your own question as to what you did.